# Find largest value and print it in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, max

I'm trying to find the largest value for a variable, where the variable must be contained in one of the list values.

My code is the following and seems to work fine, however I encounter a problem. Basically the code is overwriting the values with the last value found instead of keeping the highest one.

```
d_list = ['a','b','c']
for value in values:
    name = value['name']
    category = value['category']
    rank = value['rank']
    largest = None
    for x in d_list:
        if x in name:
           if largest is None or rank > largest:
              largest = rank
              info[x + ' ' + 'Rank'] = largest
```

Any suggestions on how to keep just the highest score for each x? Thank you

Comment: What is ``values``?  It's some kind of iterable, obviously, but what does it look like.  And what output are you trying to get?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name by the way. You're shadowing a reserved word in Python

Comment: @offbyone my guess is it's a list of dicts

Comment: @offbyone values is a list of dictionaries. Name and category are strings, rank is a float. I'd like to get the rank for each name and keep just the highest for each name, where x is in the name

Comment: @Mangohero1 sure, I actually used list as an example while I was quickly writing the post. I edited my example so there's no confusion. Thanks for flagging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
largest = {}

list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for value in values:
    rank = value['rank']

    for x in list:
        if x in value['name']:
            largest[x] = max(largest.get(x, rank), rank)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem indicates that largest is being overwritten by rank for each iteration of the for loop. I would guess that is because you need an indent after the last if statement. Python uses indents to parse conditionals, and this code is always entering the block after the last if statement because that statement has no indent.

Comment: that was just a typo my bad, I know about indents. If there wasn't any indent the code wouldn't work at all and would return an error saying that the indent is not correct...